# Selecting a value from a table into a variable without changing the formatting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

Using code similar to the below within a larger stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Foo NVARCHAR(500)
SET @Foo = (SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID = 1)    -- May be numeric or text
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyColumn] = @Foo
```

In theory, the above code should always return the same as the query

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID = 1
```

However, it often returns `(0 Rows)`. The reason for this, is that the variable `@Foo` does not always store the value found in the same format as the table.

For example, the table may contain the value `2152437`. However, the select statement above would cause this to be stored as `@Foo = 2.01512e+007`.

I have attempted to solve this problem by using the code

```
IF ISNUMERIC((SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID = 1)) = 1 SET @Foo = Str((SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID = 1))
ELSE SET @Foo = (SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID = 1)
```

The problem with this is that, although it allows large integers to be stored in `@Foo` in the same format as they are found in the database, it causes decimals to be rounded. I have also tried using the code

```
SET @Foo = Str((SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID = 1), 10, 6)
```

However, this adds unwanted 0's to the end of the value found. Thus, this is also not an option.

How might I preserve the formatting used within the database when storing a selected value into a variable - given that the value found in the database **may or may not be numeric**?

However, when decimals are found

Comment: You could use `sql_variant` instead of `nvarchar` as the variable type but a better solution is probably to get rid of the variable altogether, by combining queries, joining tables etc

Comment: BTW the problem here isn't about formatting - dates and numbers have no format, they are binary values. The problem is that the actual binary values are *converted* to strings and back again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an exact solution, but you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE CAST([MyColumn] as NVARCHAR(500)) = @Foo;
```

However, I really question what you are trying to do.  Why are you saving a numeric value in a variable?

Second, the problem that you are getting is because the column is stored using a floating point representation.  Your code will work as you intend if you switch to a fixed-point representation (`numeric`/`decimal`).  That might be the simplest fix to this problem.